# look for two string in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

How am I able to regex for two different words in a string in Groovy? Curently I can only get it to work when looking for one string.

```
def r = "This is a line that only contains LookForMe and nothing else"
def result = r =~ ('LookForMe' || 'AndMeToo')
assert result instanceof Matcher
if (result) ...
```

I want to be able to look for the words 'LookForMe' or 'AndMeToo' and perform an action if either scenario is 'true'.

Comment: And where is the string you want to match the regex against ?

Comment: defined r. Not that it matters for this example really. The question is about how to match either two strings against a single variable.

Comment: replace `||` with `|`

Comment: :O. Really? Thanks!!! I will give this a try

Comment: To be more precise: replace it with: `'LookForMe|AndMeToo'` (a single string). See: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5070015954944000

Answer (score 1):

```
def r = "This is a line that only contains LookForMe and nothing else"
def result = (r =~ /.*LookForMe.*|.*AndMeToo.*/)
if(result) ...
```